# Android YouTubePlayer API - YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver - Failed to get advertising id

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-youtube-api

I use the youtube player in fragment in YouTubePlayerActivity

**I get this kind of errors when I use it:**

- **When opening the youtube player:**

  - *Failed to get advertising id        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String iwq.a' on a null object reference*

Is advertising id compulsory?

- **When closing the youtube player activity:**

  - *Service com.google.android.youtube.api.service.YouTubeService has leaked IntentReceiver udp@bf4a7a that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?*

How can I prevent this error?

(The errors don't crash the app)

**But the app chrashes when I open and close youtube video activity quickly many times.**
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized*

```
public class YouTubePlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment mYouTubePlayerFragment;
    private YouTubePlayer mYouTubePlayer;

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube_player, container, false);

        mYouTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        mYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(VideoService.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    mYouTubePlayer = player;
                    mYouTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    mYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(mVideoID);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
                if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                    errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, mYouTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        return view;
    }

    ...

}
```

Thanks for any help!